# How to make from mpts udp (a pack of programs with id's) to video-stream with one program id (spts)

Tags: python, opencv, udp, vlc, multicast

I trying to get the link of stream with one channel (not a pack of channels which gives me mpt stream) to paste it string to opencv VideoCapure. Because if I paste it mpt stream link to VideoCapture it give me the random (one of this channels in pack) program.
For example I have link : udp://@255.1.1.7:1234 and it have pack of programs (nikelodion, blablatv, brazzerstv and etc.).

1. I can visualize necessary channel via vlc like that:

```
vlc -vv -d udp://@225.1.1.7:1234 --program=24919
```

Where --program - it's id of necessary channel.

2. I can make stream via vlc:

```
vlc --ttl 12 udp://@225.1.1.7:1234 --program=24919 --sout '#std{access=udp, mux=ts, dst=192.168.40.73:1235}'
```

but it's giving me errors. I can videocapture that stream via opencv. But it also random channels on it

Errors that happened when I ran the second command:

> ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (EIT decoder): 'last_section_number' differs whereas no discontinuity has occured
>
> main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented

Comment: please do not try to abuse opencv (a computer-vision library with limited video support) for what you're trying. tryto access ffmpeg / gstreamer directly, not through a library wrapping around those